# Default filter with partial number

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

In tree view i have field "code" and i want to filter only records when code starts with 910 and it should be default filter.
I trying to play with context but not much. i can filter by code but how can i add this 910 in there.

```
<field name="context">{"search_default_code":1}</field>
```

Update.

```
<record id="project_proposal_view_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">project.part.search</field>
    <field name="model">project.proposal</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="project_id"/>
            <field name="code"/>
            <filter name="code" string="Starts with 910" domain="[('code','ilike', '910')]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>

class ProjectProposal(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.proposal'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']

    code = fields.Char(compute='_compute_code')

 @api.multi
    @api.onchange('project_id', 'object', 'stage_id', 'part_template_id')
    def _compute_code(self):
        for r in self:
            code = []
            if r.project_id:
                code.append(r.project_id.code or '')
            if r.object:
                code.append(r.object or '')
            if r.stage_id:
                code.append(r.stage_id.code or '')
            if r.part_template_id:
               code.append(r.part_template_id.code or '')
            r.code = '-'.join(code)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to inform us about the code field type. it seems to be of type char.also it seems you are using an action with context.

so you have to define filter **code** which you are trying to use {"search_default_code":1}

```
<filter name="code" string="starts with 910" domain="[('code','ilike', '910')]" />
```

so you will end up defining something like that

```xml
<!-- FILTERS FOR YOUR MODEL -->
<record id="filter_model_name" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">FILTER NAME</field>
    <field name="model">MODEL.NAME</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="MODEL NAME">
            <filter name="code" string="starts with 910" domain="[('code','ilike', '910')]" />
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
<!-- FILTERS FOR YOUR MODEL -->
```

please make sure your field definition to be like

```py
code = fields.Char(compute='_compute_code', store=True)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but try to explain more. Where he put the filter ?

Comment: Eddited my question with more code , and yeas type is char. the problem is that it's not filtering. with or without filter the result is the same in tree view.

Comment: make sure that you've upgraded your module. you can make sure your search is loaded from Settings → Technical → Sequences & Identifiers → External Identifiers

Comment: Non-stored field project.proposal.code cannot be searched. getting this error

Comment: could you please add field definition code to your question